# Erro ao instalar laravel phplegends/pt-br-validator

Tags: laravel, validator

Ao tentar instalar o pt-br-validator via **composer require laravellegends/pt-br-validator** ou mesmo editando o arquivo do composer manualmente eu estou encontrando o seguinte erro:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]       
  Class 'PHPLegends\PtBrValidator\ValidatorProvider' not found
```

Usando Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema (instalando via composer).

A linha que deve ser adicionada ao arquivo `config/app.php` na verdade é:

> LaravelLegends\PtBrValidator\ValidatorProvider::class

Comment: Na verdade, realmente a documentação diz que o `namespace` é `LaravelLegends`. Eu sou o mantedor da biblioteca junto com outro usuário aqui do Stackoverflow. Qualquer dúvida, é só chamar no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=pt.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com a documentação do [PHPLegends](https://github.com/phplegends/laravel-pt-br-validator), essa biblioteca foi movida para outra organização, chamada [LaravelLegends](https://github.com/LaravelLegends/pt-br-validator).

Sempre que for instalar essa library, use esses passos:

- https://github.com/LaravelLegends/pt-br-validator

O composer informa, quando você vai instalar, que você deve preferir usar `laravellegends/pt-br-validator` ao invés de `phplegends/pt-br-validator`.

Eu sou o mantedor da biblioteca :)

Eu mudei o namespace `PHPLegends` para `LaravelLegends` para concentrar de maneira mais eficiente as bibliotecas que eu fosse desenvolver para o Laravel numa organização só.

Espero que essas informações lhe ajude.

Comment: Obrigado, Wallace. Cometi o erro porque visitei a página antiga de vocês. Eu sugiro que vocês editem o readme da página antiga e deixem só com o aviso e o link para o LaravelLegends, assim podemos evitar que mais pessoas cometam o mesmo erro :)

Comment: Tem um Link lá, mas tá pequeno kkkk